# MSVCP100D.DLL is missing (SFML)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I get MSVCP110D.dll is missing when I finish compiling and try to run program I wrote in C++. I have Windows 8.1 x64 and I have tried to install MV C++ 2010, but It said me that there is no need since my computer have newer version. Take a look into my code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Can somebody help me, my SubSystem is Windows, all Inputs, libs, and \include are set as It said on SFML 2.1 tuts. I use VS Express 2013. THANKS!

Comment: You need to build your application release before trying to redistribute it, you cannot redistribute `MSVCP100D.DLL` according to the license.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the mode in visual studio from **Debug** to **Release** and execute your code.

Comment: This! Can you sir, please, explain me what was the catch?

Comment: @user3502081: Debug builds are intended to run in Visual Studio. They therefore use Microsoft DLLs which work together with the Visual Studio debugger. These DLLs are distinguished from the release DLLs by their D suffix, and they are installed as part of Visual Studio. They're not found on regular PC's. It is possible that SFML also uses this convention, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

If you compile your code in Visual Studio 2010, you'll need Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86 or x64 depends on your application's architecture). Also you can change this option in your project properties. What I said was about default settings of Visual Studio.